# How do I write a Jest test for an authenticated Express endpoint?

Tags: javascript, express, unit-testing, authentication, jestjs

I have, what I thought was, a simple "plain-vanilla-ish" 4-file toy solution. I want to write a Jest test for the bingo.js authenticated route '/'. Here are the four files that show the complete set-up.

- `index.js`, the Express app root
- `routes/auth.js`, a simple authentication `POST` endpoint that checks the user
- `routes/bingo.js`, an endpoint that requires the user to be authenticated, and
- `middleware/authentication.js`, a simple middleware that checks the session user

I'm banging my head against the wall, trying to figure out how to write unit tests for the bingo.js endpoint, without having to run the entire app through `index.js` - I don't need full end-to-end tests here, that's what the Cypress tests are for.

I've tried to find ways to call just the auth step, I've tried mocking sessions, I've tried to figure out how to set the session on Supertest...

Please can someone at least point me in the right direction?

#### index.js

```js
// index.js

const express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const session = require("express-session");
const app = express();

const bingoRouter = require("./routes/bingo");
const authRouter = require("./routes/auth");

// middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(
  session({
    cookie: { maxAge: 300000 },
    store: new session.MemoryStore(),
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: "true",
    secret: "our_really_secret_key",
  })
);

app.use("/bingo", bingoRouter);
app.use("/auth", authRouter);

app.use((req, res) => {
  return res.status(404).json({
    error: "Not Found",
  });
});

app.listen(port);

module.exports = app;
```

#### auth.js

```js
// routes/auth.js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const secretKey = "our_really_secret_key";

// Authenticate user
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  const user = { username: "username", password: "password", is_admin: true };
  if (user && user.password === "password") {
    req.session.user = user;
    res.redirect("/bingo");
  } else {
    res.render("auth", { error: "Invalid username or password" });
  }
});
```

#### bingo.js

```js
// routes/bingo
const { isAdmin } = require("../middleware/authentication");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.use(isAdmin);

router.get("/", async function (req, res) {
  res.render("bingo", {
    user: req.session.user,
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

#### authentication.js

```js
// middleware/authentication.js
exports.isAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.session.user && req.session.user.is_admin) {
    // User is authenticated & admin, allow access to route
    next();
  } else {
    // User is not authenticated or not admin, redirect to login page
    res.redirect("/auth");
  }
};
```

Comment: This is what nock can be used for: https://github.com/nock/nock. You mock your auth endpoints with it returning whatever response you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To unit test your `bingo.js` endpoint using Jest and Supertest, you can mock the `isAdmin` middleware. This approach allows you to simulate an authenticated user without going through the actual authentication process. Here's how you can do it:

1. **Mock the `isAdmin` Middleware:**
   By mocking the `isAdmin` middleware, you can bypass the authentication check and directly test the behavior of your `bingo.js` route. The mock will always call `next()`, simulating an authenticated user.
2. **Example Test Setup:**

   ```js
   const request = require('supertest');
   const app = require('../index'); // Import your Express app
   const { isAdmin } = require('../middleware/authentication');

   // Mock the isAdmin middleware
   jest.mock('../middleware/authentication', () => ({
     isAdmin: (req, res, next) => next(),
   }));

   describe('GET /bingo', () => {
     it('should allow access to an authenticated user', async () => {
       const response = await request(app).get('/bingo');
       expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
       // Add more assertions as needed
     });
   });
   ```

   This test checks whether an authenticated user can access the `/bingo` route.
3. **Testing Unauthenticated Access:**
   To test the behavior for unauthenticated users, modify the mock of `isAdmin` to simulate a failed authentication, for instance, by redirecting to the login page.
4. **Adding a Known User:**
   If you need to test with a specific user object in the session, you can modify the mock to add a `req.session.user` object.
5. **Running Tests:**
   Make sure to run your Jest tests with the `--runInBand` flag to avoid issues with session handling and concurrency.

This approach focuses on the `bingo.js` route in isolation and is ideal for unit testing scenarios where you don't need to test the entire application flow.

Answer (score 1):

As [morganney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258174/morganney) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77423927/how-do-i-write-a-jest-test-for-an-authenticated-express-endpoint#comment136514476_77423927), [Nock](https://github.com/nock/nock) is not well-suited for your task.
It is designed for HTTP server mocking and expectations, primarily for testing external service calls by intercepting outgoing HTTP requests and providing programmed responses.
While it can be used to mock responses from external services, it is not for internal middleware testing in an Express application, which is what you need.

You have an authenticated Express endpoint:

```
Client ---> [Express App]
                |
                |-> /auth ---> [Auth Middleware] ---> /bingo
                |
                |-> /bingo ---> [Bingo Router]
```

You can test it (an authenticated endpoint in [Jest](https://github.com/jestjs/jest)) using [`supertest`](https://github.com/ladjs/supertest) to make requests to your Express app and `jest` to mock functions or modules. Given that you have authentication middleware, you would typically mock the session or the middleware to simulate a logged-in user.
See also as an introduction "[Testing Express Api with Jest and Supertest](https://dev.to/franciscomendes10866/testing-express-api-with-jest-and-supertest-3gf) " from [Francisco Mendes](https://dev.to/franciscomendes10866).

Since you want to test the `bingo.js` endpoint in isolation, you do not need to authenticate via the `auth.js` route. Instead, you can directly [mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions) the `isAdmin` middleware to always invoke `next()` as if the user is authenticated.

```bash
+--------+      +---------------+      +--------------+      +-------------+
| Client | ---> | Express App   | ---> | isAdmin Mock | ---> | Bingo Route |
+--------+      +---------------+      +--------------+      | (Jest Test) |
                                                             +-------------+
```

As mentioned above, use `supertest` to send requests to the `bingo.js` route. Within the test, mock the `isAdmin` middleware before importing the router.

`bingo.test.js`:

```js
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../index'); // Import your Express app
const { isAdmin } = require('../middleware/authentication');

// Mock the isAdmin middleware
jest.mock('../middleware/authentication', () => ({
  isAdmin: (req, res, next) => next(),
}));

describe('GET /bingo', () => {
  it('should allow access to an authenticated user', async () => {
    // Set up the mock session or user here if necessary
    
    const response = await request(app).get('/bingo');
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
    expect(response.body).toHaveProperty('user');
  });
});
```

This would assume that `isAdmin` is the only middleware that needs to be passed to access `/bingo`. If there are more layers of middleware that require mocking, you use a similar approach.

Make sure to run your Jest tests with the `--runInBand` flag to avoid issues with session handling and concurrency.

---

> How do I set up the mocking function to test that an unauthenticated user is redirected?
> How do I add an authenticated user to the request, i.e. have `req.session.user` set to a known object? –

To set up a test where `req.session.user` is set to a known object, you can mock the `authentication` middleware to add a user to `req.session`.

Your project would look like:

```
project-root/
│
├── index.js
├── package.json
│
├── routes/
│   ├── auth.js
│   └── bingo.js
│
├── middleware/
│   └── authentication.js
│
└── __tests__/
    └── bingo.test.js  <-- Mock session setup here
```

And `bingo.test.js` would be:

```js
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../index'); // Import your Express app

// Mock the session to include an authenticated user
const mockSession = {
  user: {
    username: "authenticatedUser",
    is_admin: true
  }
};

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.session = mockSession; // Your mock session object
  next();
});

describe('GET /bingo', () => {
  it('should render bingo for authenticated users', async () => {
    const response = await request(app).get('/bingo');
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
  });
});
```

The `mockSession` is directly injected into `req.session` before any route handling, which should effectively simulate an authenticated user's session.

That way, the `req.session.user` will be set as if the user has already authenticated when the `/bingo` route is accessed.

Comment: Thanks VonC, that's great - how do I set up the mocking function to test that an unauthenticated user is redirected?

Comment: I think my question is really, how do I add an authenticated user to the request, i.e. have req.session.user set to a known object?

Comment: @Dycey OK, I have edited the answer to address your comments/questions.